# How to get value of a key from database

Tags: android

I have used `push()` to add the unique value and corresponding order no. (in Realtime Database of Firebase.) I am struggling to get the value of the respective key (created by push()).

I want to retrieve the values : `"new-orderThu Apr 29 21:21:14 GMT+05:30 2021"` and next new-order.... blah blah..

[image: a]

I managed to get the full string value `(console screen shot enclosed)` , but I want to get only  `"new-orderThu Apr 29 21:21:14 GMT+05:30 2021"` . This is my code

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(flag){
                    
                    for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d("User val", child.getValue().toString());
                     }

                    flag = false;
                }
            }
```

[image]

Can you help, how to get the value.. `"new-orderThu Apr 29 21:21:14 GMT+05:30 2021"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to go one level deeper in your child tree, if you dont know the key (MZ...)

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(flag){
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("User val", child.getValue().toString());
            // If you know there is only a single child
            dataSnapshot.getChildren().next() // will give you the first/only item
            
            // Otherwise, iterate again:
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("User val", child.getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        flag = false;
    }
}
```